# Length of Curve $6xy=3+x^4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question :

> Find the length of the curve $6xy=3+x^4$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$.
>
> **Answer** = 17/12

I have tried this:
[image]
[image]

I obtain a different answer. Where did I do wrongly?

**Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is not correct. Note that
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x^4-1}{2x^2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{x^8+2x^4+1}{4x^4}}=\frac{x^4+1}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+x^{-2})$$
and now the integration is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Your integration is not correct.  You should simplify the integrand before proceeding.  We have $$\mathscr{L}=\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x^{4}-1}{2x^2}\right)^{2}}dx=\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{\frac{(x^{4}+1)^2}{4x^4}}dx\\=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^{4}+1}{2x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2} x^2\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x^2}dx\\=\frac{1}{6}x^3\biggr|_{1}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x}\biggr|_{1}^{2}=\frac{17}{12}$$